# Find the center of a circle (x and y position) with only 2 random points and bulge

Tags: algorithm, math, unity-game-engine, date-arithmetic

im trying to find the center of a circle. the only information I have is:
Two random points in the circle and the circle bulge. So far i've manage to calculate the radius of the circle (at least i think i did). Ill post bellow the equasions ive used so far.

these are just random values and will change on user input)

PointA(x = 10, y = 15)
PointB(x = 6, y = 12)

circle_bulge = 0.41

distance = PointB - PointA

radius = (distance / 4) * (circle_bulge + (1 / circle_bulge ))

if this math is incorrect, please let me know, but keep in mind that i need to find the X and Y coordinates of the center of the circle

Comment: This will result in two possible solutions for every case where the two points aren't directly opposite on the circle.

Comment: Yes there will allways be 2 circles, however, i believe that i can find out wich one is the correct one using the bulge again. If bulge is positive, ill get one, if its negative, its the other. i just didnt want to talk about it to avoid over-complicating things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a picture of the problem:

[image]

By definition the bulge is *b* = tg(*Alpha*/4)

From the trigonometric formula: tg(2 *angle*) = 2tg(*angle*)/(1-tg<sup>2</sup>(*angle*))

applied to *angle* = *Alpha*/4 and using the definition of bulge:

tg(*Alpha*/2) = 2 *b*/(1-*b*<sup>2</sup>)

On the other hand

tg(*Alpha*/2) = *s*/*d*

Then

*s*/*d* = 2 *b*/(1-*b*<sup>2</sup>) and

*d* = *s*(1-*b*<sup>2</sup>)/(2 *b*)

which allows us to calculate *d* because *b* is known and *s* = ||*B* - *A*||/2, where ||*B* - *A*|| denotes the norm of the vector *B* - *A*.

Now, let's calculate

(*u*,*v*) = (*B* - *A*)/||*B* - *A*||

Then ||(*u*,*v*)|| = 1, (*v*,-*u*) is orthogonal to *B* - *A*, and we have

*C* = (*v*,-*u*)*d* + (*A*+*B*)/2

---

**UPDATE**

Pseudo code to compute the center

**Inputs:**

```
A = (a1, a2), B = (b1, b2) "two points"; b "bulge"
```

**Calculations:**

```
"lengths"
norm := sqrt(square(b1-a1) + square(b2-a2)).
s := norm/2.
d := s * (1-square(b))/(2*b)

"direction"
u := (b1-a1)/ norm.
v := (b2-a2)/ norm.

"center"
c1 := -v*d + (a1+b1)/2.
c2 := u*d + (a2+b2)/2.
Return C := (c1, c2)
```

*Note:* There are two solutions for the Center, the other one being

```
c1 := v*d + (a1+b1)/2.
c2 := -u*d + (a2+b2)/2.
Return C := (c1, c2)
```

Comment: Call me an idiot but i didnt understand half of what you wrote here :(

Comment: That's fine. Just help me to clarify my answer. What's the first thing you don't quite understand?

Comment: I dont understand how can i translate this math to coding. Dont know if you have any experience with that...

Comment: I've added the pseudo-code. Please let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: That is alot simples thanks alot :)

Just another question, how do i "close" this topic to show it has been answered?

Comment: You can click on the check mark below the voting points spin to declare an answer **the** answer. Additionally, you can up vote the answers you consider interesting or informative. There can only be one answer with the checkmark, but you can up vote all of them.

Comment: tg(2 angle) = tg2(angle)/(1-tg2(angle)) Should this be tg(2 angle) = 2tg(angle)/(1-tg2(angle))?

Comment: @RyanWang you are right. I've updated the answer. Thanks a lot for calling my attention.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you have all the required math in this reference: http://autocad.wikia.com/wiki/Arc_relationships

The center of the circunference has to be in the straight line that passes trough the middle point of the segment with perpendicular vector AB. You know the angle of the triangle formed by the three points because you know the bulge so you have to solve a simple equation. Try it out, if you can not I will try to help you.

Ignacio is right pointing out that there will be two solutions.

EDIT

The middle point is given by:

```
M = (A + B) / 2
```

The AB vector is gien by:

```
AB = A-B
```

The center of the circle C with coordinates (X, Y) has to be in the line given by:

```
((X, Y) - M) * AB = 0 //where * is the scalar vector product
```

The isosceles triangle generated by the points A, B and C has an angle opposite of the AB segment:

```
Angle = 4 arctan(bulge)
```

now we can compute the distance from the center C to A that we call d1 and half the distance between A and B that we call d2 we know then that

```
sin (Angle/2) = d2/d1
```

This will give you the second equation for X and Y that is quadratic (it has two solutions).

Excuse the notation but I do not know how to insert math here :-)

Comment: This is but a small part of a larger function. I dont know if i cant find it because im too tired (been working on this the entire day) or if im too stupid to understand the next time. if you could give me some more points, would be very helpfull